# The multi-part identifier "T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name" could not be bound in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like this:

```
select  itemcode, itemdescription, max(somecol1) as outgoing, max(somecol2) as incoming
  from (  select ItemCode,ItemDescription, CASE  WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND  
  dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code 
  THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)   ELSE 0 END as somecol1, 
   CASE  WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND 
    dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
     THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)   ELSE 0  END as somecol2  
        from T_Item_Movement  
         where T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code='12008' 
        and convert(varchar(10),F_datetime,112) >= '20130920' and  
         convert(varchar(10),F_datetime,112) <= '20150920'  group by 
         ItemCode,ItemDescription,T_Item_Movement.F_Status,  
         T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code, T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code  ) t 
          group by itemcode, itemdescription
```

this query working fine.but i want to get my F.Sitecode name so i re-write my query like this:

```
select T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name, itemcode, itemdescription, max(somecol1) as outgoing, max(somecol2) as incoming
  from (  select ItemCode,ItemDescription, CASE  WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 1 AND  
  dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code 
  THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)   ELSE 0 END as somecol1, 
   CASE  WHEN dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Status = 2 AND 
    dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code <> dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code
     THEN SUM(dbo.T_Item_Movement.F_Quantity)   ELSE 0  END as somecol2  
        from T_Item_Movement  
        inner join T_Exhibition on T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Code=T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code
         where T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code='12008' 
        and convert(varchar(10),F_datetime,112) >= '20130920' and  
         convert(varchar(10),F_datetime,112) <= '20150920'  group by 
         ItemCode,ItemDescription,T_Item_Movement.F_Status,  
         T_Item_Movement.F_Site_Code, T_Item_Movement.F_Frm_Site_Code,T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name  ) t 
          group by itemcode, itemdescription
```

but now i am getting error :The multi-part identifier **"T_Exhibition.F_Exhibition_Name" could not be bound.**

Answer (score 0):

Error Message is pretty clear, change alias name `t_exhibition` to `t`. Because `t_exhibition` is used inside the `sub-select`.

```
SELECT t.f_exhibition_name, --here
       itemcode, 
       itemdescription, 
       Max(somecol1) AS outgoing, 
       Max(somecol2) AS incoming 
FROM   (Select.....) t 
GROUP  BY itemcode, 
          itemdescription
```